# Facebook FQL and Statuses from multiple profiles

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Wondering if anyone has had any success pulling statues from multiple profiles, something like the below:

```
select uid, status_id, time, message from status where uid in (?)
```

seems to return some data occasionally, but only intermittently, and not the full list of uid's supplied.

```
select uid, status_id, time, message from status where uid = ?
```

works fine. Anyone with any ideas..?